# C++ rewrite vector of floats with more elements

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following vectors:

```cpp
vector<float> data = { 1.2, 4.3, 2.4 };
vector<float> newdata;
```

I then want to fill `newdata` with `n` number of elements that mimic as closely as possible the data held in `data`. `n` may be more or less than the number of elements in `data`. How do I do this?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "mimic" the data. You can use simple assignment to get the exact values of the data. Please describe your use case in more detail.

Comment: `std::vector<float> newdata = data;   newdata.resize(n);`  will do it.   If `n` is greater than the number of elements in `data`, zeros will be appended.   If less than, the excess elements will be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor getting a range as input and compute the correct length of the range:

```
std::size_t n = ...;
std::vector<float> data = { 1.2, 4.3, 2.4 };
std::vector<float> newdata(data.begin(), data.begin() + std::min(data.size(), n));
```